# combining two arrays that have the same field in node js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, combinations

**I have arrays like these**

```
arr1 = [{
    "_id": 1,
    "item": "Pencil",
    "color": "Red"
  },{
    "_id":2,
    "item": "Pen",
    "color": "Yellow"
  },{
    "_id": 3,
    "item": "Pencil",
    "color": "Green"
}]

arr2 = [{
    "value":"Pencil",
    "price":1000,
 },{
    "value":"Pen",
    "price":1500,
 }]
```

**How do I combine this arr2 into arr1 with "value" in arr2 and "price" in arr1 as the key? so that it has the following results**

```
res = [{
        "_id": 1,
        "item": "Pencil",
        "color": "Red",
        "price": 1000
      },{
        "_id":2,
        "item": "Pen",
        "color": "Yellow",
        "price": 1500
      },{
        "_id": 3,
        "item": "Pencil",
        "color": "Green",
        "price": 1000
    }]
```

Comment: i've tried use forEach tu push the price. but gave wrong result like this :

Comment: [ { '0': { value: 'Panorama BJB', path: 5e4fedd5e18ba14d11047eda },
    '1': { value: 'Tokopedia', path: 5e4fd5b2e18ba14d11047be0 },
    '$__':
     InternalCache {
       strictMode: true,
       selected: [Object],
       shardval: undefined,
       saveError: undefined,
       validationError: undefined,
       adhocPaths: undefined,
       removing: undefined,
       inserting: undefined,
       saving: undefined,
       version: undefined,
       getters: {},
       _id: 5e1578b48c52231ee19f83e4,
       populate: undefined,
       populated: undefined,

Comment: still googling hehe im really newbie at this.

Comment: im trying .push()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) collection to have `O(1)` while mapping the second array:

```
const uniquePencils = new Map(arr2.map(s => [s.value, s.price]));
const result = arr1.map(a => ({...a, price: uniquePencils.get(a.item)}));
```

[As mdn says about Map collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map):

> The Map object holds key-value pairs and remembers the original
>   insertion order of the keys.

So to create a map collection from array we can [use map method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
const uniquePencils = new Map(arr2.map(s => [s.value, s.price]));
```

Then when we map array, we need to give item name(e.g. Pencil) to Map collection to `get` object from map collection.

```
arr1.map(a => ({...a, price: uniquePencils.get(a.item)}));
```

In addition, we've used `...` operator. It is called spread syntax. [It copies own enumerable properties from a provided object onto a new object.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

An example:

```js
let arr1 = [{
  "_id": 1,
  "item": "Pencil",
  "color": "Red"
},{
  "_id":2,
  "item": "Pen",
  "color": "Yellow"
},{
  "_id": 3,
  "item": "Pencil",
  "color": "Green"
}];

let arr2 = [{
  "value":"Pencil",
  "price":1000,
},{
  "value":"Pen",
  "price":1500,
}];

const uniquePencils = new Map(arr2.map(s => [s.value, s.price]));
const result = arr1.map(a => ({...a, price: uniquePencils.get(a.item)}));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: oh, i just found out how to use s => [s.value, s.price] and get() inside map.thank you very much

Comment: in my real case, i've still bad model array data. and I'm confused to ask. and I chose to ask about the case above. still looking for inspiration. sorry if it's not clear

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map`. For example:

```
let arr3 = arr1.map((el1) => {
    let found = arr2.find(el2 => el1.item == el2.value)
    if (found)
        el1.price = found.price
    return el1
})

console.log(arr3)
```